# /bin/bash -c access to unexported variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to understand why the following happens:
After setting up a variable like `var1=test` in the current shell, without exporting it (so it will not be available in child processes) and execute  `/bin/bash -c "echo $var1"` right after, I can see the unexported variable.
I am aware of the fact that a builtin command like "echo" does not fork() or exec(), so it would have access to the unexported `$var1` or about the fact that a SUBSHELL would have access to the unexported variables too.

But in my case, `/bin/bash -c "command"` is not a SUBSHELL either as `/bin/bash -c "echo $BASH_SUBSHELL"` would show me "`0`". And I thought it should behave the same as an external command, so -> `fork` -> `exec` and inherit environment variables from the parent.
So, for example, I see the following behaivor:

```
[nimus@localhost ~]$ echo $var1
test
[nimus@localhost ~]$ /bin/bash
[nimus@localhost ~]$ echo $var1

[nimus@localhost ~]$ exit
exit
[nimus@localhost ~]$ /bin/bash -c "echo $var1; echo $BASH_SUBSHELL"
test
0
[nimus@localhost ~]$
```

So how is `/bin/bash -c "command"` different then an external command or `fork` and `exec` a new whole bash Shell like above?

Thanks!

Comment: Another misunderstanding: `echo` (a builtin or not) does not "have access to the unexported `$var1`". It doesn't get `$var`, it gets the *expanded* string(s).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: The shell dose a lot of hard work. It is well worth continuing on your journey learning how it works.